# How to limit amount of records in a double table with a function mysql query

Tags: mysql, sql, limit, levenshtein-distance, fuzzy-search

What is the correct way to limit the amount of records from list1: ([original source](http://jjustinwilson.com/post/55784230101/fuzzy-logic-joins-in-mysql))

```
select `List 1`.`name`, `List 2`.`name`,
       levenshtein_ratio(`List 1`.`name`, `List 2`.`name`)
FROM `List 1`, `List 2`
```

The following gives 0 as result:

```
select `List 1`.`name`, `List 2`.`name`,
       levenshtein_ratio(`List 1`.`name`, `List 2`.`name`)
FROM `List 1`, `List 2`
LIMIT 0 , 15500
```

Comment: That looks like the correct way ([manual page for SELECT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/select.html)) to get up to the first 15,500 records.  What is the field structure of the result?

Comment: there is no field structure, the result is only: "0"

Comment: How many records are in `List 1` and `List 2`?

Comment: I tried LIMIT 50000 , 100000 ; and the result is still the same.

Comment: ~0.7million records in each list.